# Adding pic on the fly to MS excel with OpenTBS

Tags: php, excel, tinybutstrong, opentbs

It was noted that ope=changepic is not possible on xlsx templates. Is there a workaround to this? Maybe thru addpic? Or maybe modifying the archive? How?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be supported in the next OpenTBS version, which will be 1.8.0.

The beta version can be downloaded at the web site:
  http://www.tinybutstrong.com/news.php

Th reason for this bug is that XLSX documents save the image size differently than DOCX and PPTX.